# Can't delete projects in Google Developer Console

Tags: google-api, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to delete projects in Google Developer Console, but receiving: "Server error". 
Chrome dev console tells me that ajax request returns "500 Internal Server Error".
Normally I would give up on this, but the problem is that this projects somehow contain oAuth "Client ID" (with wrong fingerprint, bug correct package id) which isn't visible under "Credentials" but persist in the system and make new "Client ID" (with correct fingerprint) incorrect.

I'm 99% sure this is bug in Google Developer Console. Desperately need help

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a project from the Developers Console releases all resources used within the project. Only project owners can delete or restore projects.

To delete a project, do the following:

Go to the Google Developers Console.
Select a project.
In the sidebar on the left, select Billing & Settings.
Click Delete project. A confirmation screen describing what will happen appears.
To confirm, enter your project ID and click Delete project.
Deleting a project stops all billing and traffic serving, deletes any App Engine applications, and terminates all Compute Engine instances. All data associated with Google Cloud services become inaccessible.

After a 7-day waiting period, the project and associated data are permanently deleted from the Developers Console.

Note that after the 7-day waiting period ends, the time it takes to completely delete a project may vary. For example, if a project has billing set up, it may not be completely deleted until the current billing cycle ends, you receive the next bill, and your account is successfully charged. Additionally, the number and types of services in use may also affect when the system permanently deletes a project.

[Google Developers Console Help](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#creatingdeletingprojects)

Comment: I read docs. The problem is that after I hit "Delete project", I receive an "Server Error".

Comment: @clayton33 yep, I created bug through google play dev console and after week or so it has been fixed

Comment: @Roman i cannot find how to create a bug in the GPDC, how did you do this?

Comment: I do not know what is wrong with me. But For several months my projects are in pending mode only. Projects shut down and pending deletion. Any Idea ?